# Change javascript object structure

Tags: javascript

I have an object format like this :

```
var groupArray=[{
  name: "blabla bla",
  code: "1"
},
{
  name: "blabla bla2",
  code: "12"
},
{
  name: "blabla bla3",
  code: "123"
}];
```

I would transform it to this structure

```
var groupArray=[{
  type: "Grp",
  code: "1"
},
{
  type: "Grp",
  code: "12"
},
{
  type: "Grp",
  code: "123"
}];
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhw8xewy/118/) demo

```
function update() {
  var array = "";
  var arrayreturn = this.getPrice(this.groupArray);
  alert(arrayreturn)
  arrayreturn.map(function(elm) {
    this.array += elm + " ";
  });
  document.getElementById("objectTransform").innerHTML = array;
}

var groupArray = [{
    name: "blabla bla",
    code: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "blabla bla2",
    code: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "blabla bla3",
    code: "123"
  }
];

function getPrice(array) {
  var newObject = [{
    typeObject: "",
    code: ""
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newObject[i].typeObject = "group";
    newObject[i].code = array[i].code
  }
  return newObject
}
```

My problem is when I click on the button to change the structure of my object I got no result

Comment: You need to push new elements in the `newObject` array (`newObject.push({typeObject: "group", code: array[i].code})`), initially, this array has only one value which means that `newObject[1]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access to an index that doesn't exist.

Just push the new elements to the new array.

```js
function update() {
  var array = "";
  var arrayreturn = this.getPrice(this.groupArray);
  console.log(arrayreturn)
  arrayreturn.map(function(elm) {
    this.array += elm + " ";
  });
  document.getElementById("objectTransform").innerHTML = array;
}

var groupArray = [{    name: "blabla bla",    code: "1"  },  {    name: "blabla bla2",    code: "12"  },  {    name: "blabla bla3",    code: "123"  }];

function getPrice(array) {
  var newObject = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newObject.push({
      type: 'Grp',
      code: array[i].code
    });
  }

  return newObject
}
```

```html
<button onClick="update();">Click me</button>

<div id="objectTransform">PRICE HERE</div>
```

An alternative using the function `map`

```js
function update() {
  var array = "";
  var arrayreturn = this.getPrice(this.groupArray);
  console.log(arrayreturn)
  arrayreturn.map(function(elm) {
    this.array += elm + " ";
  });
  document.getElementById("objectTransform").innerHTML = array;
}

var groupArray = [{    name: "blabla bla",    code: "1"  },  {    name: "blabla bla2",    code: "12"  },  {    name: "blabla bla3",    code: "123"  }];

function getPrice(array) {
  return array.map(function(o) {
    return { type: 'Grp', code: o.code }
  });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="update();">Click me</button>

<div id="objectTransform">PRICE HERE</div>
```